# Segue from segmentcontrol in XIB Viewcontroller to Storyboard Viewcontroller

Tags: xib, segue

I have a segment control in a viewcontroller (UISegmentController.h, UISegmentController.m, UISegmentController.xib) created in a xib. Now I am trying to segue (ideally push) to Storyboard viewcontroller (ChartviewController.h, ChartviewController.m) I created. This Viewcontroller will hold images. I tried to perform this push as below:

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged;
{

//some code
ChartViewController *chartviewpage = [[ChartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chartviewpage animated:YES];
//some code
}
```

I used to implement this code to another xib viewcontroller and it worked fine. But now not with the stroryboard viewcontroller.
However, I receive an exception as follows:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ChartViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15e6012 0x11b3e7e 0x15e5deb 0x53ffac 0x404e37 0x405418 0x405648 0x405882 0x405b2a 0x41cef5 0x41cfdb 0x41d286 0x41d381 0x41deab 0x41e4a3 0x41e098 0x4048 0x11c7705 0x327920 0x3278b8 0x3e8671 0x3e8bcf 0x3e86a6 0x43d597 0x43f83b 0x35716d 0x357552 0x3353aa 0x326cf8 0x22d1df9 0x22d1ad0 0x155bbf5 0x155b962 0x158cbb6 0x158bf44 0x158be1b 0x22d07e3 0x22d0668 0x32465c 0x1d0d 0x1c35)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Can u help please?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out doing a bit more research. first, one needs to instantiate the controller (ChartViewcontroller) in the storyboard they are trying to transition to. Then you need to give a storyboard ID name (ChartID) to the controller which can be find under the file inspector after selecting the controller. Finally perform the push to the new controller.

Hope this helps someone.

UIStoryboard * myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ChartViewController *chartpage = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChartID"];

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chartpage animated:YES];